# Assigning to a isolate scope object outside of $watch within a directive yields unpredictable behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

At work, we use AngularJS as our front end. Ours is a massively forms driven app and requires a lot of reusable components.

We model these reusable components as directives with isolate scope. This makes sense for us because there are multiple cases where we end up using the same directive 2 times on a page.

When doing this, I seem to have encountered a problem relating to isolate scope object's being set from outside a `$watch` function.

### Scenario:

- Each directive has its own isolate scope
- Each directive receives its inputs via a `load-id` attribute
- The `load-id` attribute has a `$watch` on it and reacts to change.
- Each directive performs an operation (a simple increment in this case) on the value received via `load-id` and binds the result to the `result` attribute so that it is accessible to the parent scope.
- This increment operation is performed **inside** a `increment` method called from the `$watch`.

### Usage:

```
<div foo-bar load-id="{{loadId1}}" result="res1"></div>
<pre>{{ res1 }}</pre>

<div foo-bar load-id="{{loadId2}}" result="res2"></div>
<pre>{{ res2 }}</pre>

<div foo-bar load-id="{{loadId3}}" result="res3"></div>
<pre>{{ res3 }}</pre>
```

### Expectation (relative to above mentioned usage):

`res1`, `res2` and `res3` will be `loadId1`, `loadId2` and `loadId3` incremented by 1 respectively.

### Reality

The last directive result (`res3` in our case) is the only object bound. `res1` and `res2` stay undefined.

Here is the simplest way to reproduce the problem: http://jsbin.com/henixicubo/1/edit?html,js,output.

### Additional research

After some digging around, I've come to notice that if we **don't** use the `increment` function and bind to `scope.result` directly within the `$watch`, things work fine.

Here is the same example as above, but **not** using the `increment` function: http://jsbin.com/figizecadi/1/edit?html,js,output which works completely as expected.

---

This is really puzzling to me. Am I doing something wrong here? Is my understanding of scopes **totally** whack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that your increment function is a global function (it's assigned to window object), JavaScript uses function scope (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp), if you define your function (with `var`) it will work. I have modified your code, try out this one: http://jsbin.com/lohizibure/edit?html,js,output

Comment: wow this is embarrassing. Although is it possible for you to articulate _why_ a `window` function behaves this way? How does it select the `scope` of the **last** directive in the DOM?

Comment: @Shrayas `window.increment` is redefined 3 times (each time that directive `link` runs). It is hardcoded to use `scope` object from function scope (`link` function). Which is the last one in a row. Always use strict mode with 'use strict', it is there to prevent awkward situations like that.

Comment: Ah I see. I understand. Thank you for your explanation. Lesson learnt :)